Determinant of a Hankel Matrix
I have a following Hankel matrix (for $c > 1$)
$$
H_n = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  c+1 & \frac{c-1}{2} & \frac{c+1}{3} & \ldots & \frac{c+(-1)^n}{n+1} \\
  \frac{c-1}{2} & \frac{c+1}{3} & \frac{c-1}{4} & \ldots & \frac{c+(-1)^{n+1}}{n+2} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  \frac{c+(-1)^n}{n+1} & \frac{c+(-1)^{n+1}}{n+2} & \ldots & \ldots & \frac{c+(-1)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}  
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The general form of the coefficients is $\ c_{i+j} = \dfrac{c+(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j+1} \; (0 \leq i,j \leq n)$
Is it possible to calculate the determinant of $H_n$? Or maybe it asymptotic?
In Advanced Determinant Calculus paper authors calculate determinant of a Hankel matrix with coefficients $\{ \frac{1}{X_i + Y_j} \}$, in my case this is a small perturbation of such matrix with the matrix $\{ \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j+1} \}$, but I have no idea how to use this fact.

What's your indexing convention? The $11$ (top-left) element of the matrix should be $c+1$, but if I substitute $i=j=1$ in $c_{i+j}$, I get $\frac{c+1}3$.

@Pranay $0 \leq i, j \leq n$.
